# CSS percentage padding on <a> tag

Tags: html, css

There may be a simple fix for this, but troubled me...

There are a `Header` and `NavBar` with some `<a>` items.

**The problem :**

When i'm using e.g. `padding: 20px` it working fine, but when use percentage `%` padding e.g. `padding: 10%` instead `px`, the result is not looks like something that should be.

You can see clearly in below.

Thanks in advance.

[DEMO in JsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/YhX2r/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="Header">
 <div id="NavBar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contant</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#Header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
#NavBar ul { list-style-type: none;}
#NavBar ul li { float: left; }
#NavBar ul li a {
    padding: 50px; /* It works fine */
    padding: 15%; /* The problem is here */
    background-color: #12aeef;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list item needs dimensions to calculate a %. Try this:

```
#NavBar ul li a {
padding: 15%; 
display:inline-block;
height: 100%;
width: 80px;
background-color: #12aeef;
}
```

Updated fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/YhX2r/10/

Comment: an element does have dimensions to calculate the % without explicitly specifying width...

Answer (score 3):

When you use a percentage in CSS, what total the percentage refers to depends on what property you are working with. In [the CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-padding), there is a little table for `padding`:

> **'padding'**
>
> > *Value*:     <padding-width>{1,4} | inherit
> >     *Initial*:      see individual properties
> >     *Applies to*:   all elements except table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group and table-column
> >     *Inherited*:    no
> >     **Percentages:      refer to width of containing block**
> >     Media:      visual
> >     Computed value:     see individual properties

But what is a containing block?

[The details are complicated](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details), but the part that applies in your case is subrule (4)(2), which says

> The containing block of an element is defined as … 
>   the containing block is formed by the padding edge of the ancestor.

That is, the size of the padding when specified as a percentage refers to the size of the box after applying the padding! Since you’re defining something in terms of itself, which doesn’t make any sense, the browser does something nonsensical.

That’s the why—what can you do about it? The easiest thing is, as you found, to just use something other than percentages to specify the padding in this case.

Comment: Brilliant explanation. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/YhX2r/7/

```
display: inline-block;
padding: 0 15%;
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display for good explanation of all display options

Answer (score 2):

You should apply a width to the "li" and not the "a"

```
#NavBar ul li { 
float: left; 
width: 15%;
background-color: #12aeef;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To explain the observed behavior:

> padding: 10% instead px, the result is not looks like something that should be.

Well, it does – although it might not be what you expected or want.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#padding-properties:

> *“The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block, even for 'padding-top' and 'padding-bottom'.”*

Answer (score 1):

`<a>` elements are `display: inline` by default, which don't allow you to deal with percentages.
Try using `display: inline-block` in your CSS, it *may not* break your design (but I can be wrong)